# ASP.NET Core Web Application Runs in IDE but not in Web Server

Tags: asp.net, windows, asp.net-core, .net-7.0, iis-10

I have a web application with a Target Framwork of .NET 7.0.  I have installed the hosting bundle for .NET 7.0 on the windows 2016 server with IIS 10.  However, the application will not run with an error:

HTTP Error 500.31 - Failed to load ASP.NET Core runtime
Common solutions to this issue:
The specified version of Microsoft.NetCore.App or Microsoft.AspNetCore.App was not found.

How can this be resolved?

Also, please note that the web application was upgraded from .NET 6.0 to .NET 7.0 prior to the issue happening.

Thanks.

Comment: how.. did you build the thing? the files you put on IIS?

Comment: Bagus, I used the Build... Build Solution menu in Visual Studio 2022.  The I published the solution to a folder configured as 'Release' with a Target framework of net7.0 and a Deployment mode of Framework-dependent.

Comment: Run a report https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html and the cause should be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution to this issue is to check the version of the ASP.NET Core runtime that your application is targeting and make sure that it is installed on the server.

You can then go to the official download page with [Download .NET 7.0](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0) Link and download the Hosting Bundle for Windows. This will install the ASP.NET Core runtime and the IIS support for hosting ASP.NET Core applications.

After installing the hosting bundle, you may need to restart the IIS service or the server for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Ahmad,  thanks for your reply.  I see the Target framework specified in Visual Studio 2022 is .NET 7.0.  I am not familiar with how to check the ASP.NET Core runtime version.  I did download and install the Hosting Bundle for Windows and restarted IIS and the server.  I am still not able use the web application.

Comment: Please run the dotnet version command in cmd and if the version is 7 and you haven't restarted your computer after installing it, do it once.

Answer (score 0):

I setup a new VM Server and installed the .NET 7.0 Hosting Bundle and it is working now.  Unfortunately, I was not able to configure this on the original server, but the new server is working properly.